# Setup bitbucket pipelines yaml file

Tags: yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to using bitbucket was trying just to set up simple build pipeline. Clicked on pipeline menu option and edited the example file and committed. This created a pipeline yaml file on my master branch. It ran and built ok - it did not build my develop branch.

Do i need a pipeline yaml file on each branch.

I can see from docs that i can put branch specific steps into the one file, if i edit the file that has been commited on master to include a section for the develop branch, will this run when i do a commit to the develop branch or will this only trigger on a commit to master branch.

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html - tells me i need to put the same file in each branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitbucket will run the pipelines that has a corresponding definition for the branch that you have commited to. So, if you commit the pipelines configuration file to master, only `default` or `master` pipeline from this file will be executed. If you want to run a pipeline for `develop` branch, you need to commit this file to develop branch as well. Note, that the `default` pipeline is executed regardless of the branch name if there is no other pipeline defined for this particular branch. So, your comment is correct, you need to have the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in each branch.

Here is how Bitbucket will resolve the pipeline execution configuration^

1. If there is no `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` - no pipelines will run for the branch
2. If there is `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` and there is a `default` pipeline definition only, Bitbucket will execute the `default` pipeline.

   ```
   pipelines:
     default:
       - step:
         script:
           - echo "Running the default pipeline"
   ```
3. If there is also a specific pipeline defined for a particular branch, lets say for `develop`, Bitbucket will execute this pipeline instead of the `default`

   ```
   pipelines:
     default:
       - step:
         script:
           - echo "This will not be executed if the branch is develop"
     develop:
       - step:
         script:
           - echo "Running the develop pipeline"
   ```

   Note, that if the branch name would be something else, lets say `release`, since there is no pipeline defined for `release` branch, the default pipeline will be executed.

Comment: thank you for your help - the docs have the information spread out all over the place.